# Reading from golang channels in order

Tags: go, parallel-processing, channel

I'm trying to achieve parallel processing and communication over the channels in go.

What I basically try to solve is process a specifc data in parallel, and get results in order => introduced type `Chunk` for the purpose (see bellow).

I just make new channel for each chunk processing and keep them in slice => expect to be ordered once I iterate over them afterwards.

Simplified version of my program is (https://play.golang.org/p/RVtDGgUVCV):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Chunk struct {
    from int
    to   int
}

func main() {
    chunks := []Chunk{
        Chunk{
            from: 0,
            to:   2,
        },
        Chunk{
            from: 2,
            to:   4,
        },
    }

    outChannels := [](<-chan struct {
        string
        error
    }){}

    for _, chunk := range chunks {
        outChannels = append(outChannels, processChunk(&chunk))
    }

    for _, outChannel := range outChannels {
        for out := range outChannel {
            if out.error != nil {
                fmt.Printf("[ERROR] %s", out.error)
                return
            }

            fmt.Printf("[STDOUT] %s", out.string)
        }
    }
}

func processChunk(c *Chunk) <-chan struct {
    string
    error
} {

    outChannel := make(chan struct {
        string
        error
    })

    go func() {
        outChannel <- struct {
            string
            error
        }{fmt.Sprintf("from: %d to: %d\n", c.from, c.to), nil}

        close(outChannel)
    }()

    return outChannel
}
```

The output I see is:

```
[STDOUT] from: 2 to: 4
[STDOUT] from: 2 to: 4
```

What I'd however expect to see would be:

```
[STDOUT] from: 0 to: 2
[STDOUT] from: 2 to: 4
```

What am I doing wrong here? I don't see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble is in the very first `for` loop of `main`. When you use `for range` loop, the loop variable (`chunk` here) gets created once and is assigned a copy of each slice element per iteration.

When you call `processChunk(&chunk)`, you are passing the address of this loop variable, and the value of this variable changes with each iteration. Thus the function `processChunk` always ends up working on the last item in the `chunks` loop since that is what `*chunk` points to after the for loop finishes.

To fix, use slice indexing:

```
for i := 0; i < len(chunks); i++ {
    // pass chunk objects by indexing chunks
    outChannels = append(outChannels, processChunk(&chunks[i]))
}
```

Fixed code: https://play.golang.org/p/A1_DtkncY_

You can read more about `range` [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements).